Prove that $A$ is homotopy equivalent to $S^1$
Disclaimer: I have not yet learned about the higher homotopy groups, so any answer not using them would be best for me.
The following problem occurred on a recent topology qualifier from Rice University:

Let $X$ be a topological space, $A \subset X$ a subspace, and $r: X \to A$ a retraction (i.e. $r(x)=x$ for all $x \in A$). Suppose $r_*: \pi_1(X) \to \pi_1(A)$ is injective and that $X$ is homotopy equivalent to $S^1$. Prove that $A$ is homotopy equivalent to $S^1$.

We know that there exists continuous $f:X\to S^1$, $g:S^1 \to X$ such that $f\circ g \cong 1_{S^1}$ and $g\circ f \cong 1_X$. My thought is to show that $f|_A$ and $r\circ g$ are homotopy inverses of each other, so that $X$ is homotopy equivalent to $A$. I see that $(r \circ g) \circ f|_A \cong r \circ 1_A$ = $1_A$, but I have not shown yet that $f|_A \circ (r \circ g) \cong 1_{S^1}$. I want to use the given injection somehow, but to me it is unclear.

I believe that the most painless way to solve this exercise is to analyse which map induce an inclusion of A into X on the level of homotopy groups. For example, the fact that A is a retract of X implies that this map is an injection. For example, using the fact that all higher homotopy groups, starting with the 2nd one, of X are 0, one can show that inclusion map induces isomorphism on these homotopy groups (since there is only one injection to the trivial group). If you still will have problems, then I can write everything explicitly in an answer

@EgorKosolapov I haven't yet learned about the higher homotopy groups, but I appreciate the input.

@MichaelCatliMath: Egor was not referring to higher homotopy groups. He was referring to $\pi_1(X)$ which is the first homotopy group of $X$ and to $\pi_1(A)$ which is the first homotopy group of $A$. So perhaps his comment is worth another read through.

@LeeMosher If that's the case, then, respectfully, I definitely don't understand what he meant.

@EgorKosolapov May you please write your thoughts explicitly in an answer?

@LeeMosher Please read Egors comment again. They are referring to higher homotopy groups, and quite explicitly so.

@MichaelCatliMath So here's one proof, which I think may be related to what Egor is thinking of: The condition on $r_*$ implies that it induces an isomorphism on all homotopy groups, so $A$ is weakly equivalent to $S^1$. Moreover, $A$ is a retract of a space with the htpy. type of a CW-complex and therefore has the htpy. type of a CW-complex itself, so this weak equivalence is in fact a homotopy equivalence, q.e.d. This obviously uses more machinery than you have access to; maybe putting a disclaimer that you don't know about higher htpy. groups would be a good idea.

@BenSteffan I see, thank you for the reply. I’ve edited my post accordingly.

ah, right, I missed the "all". @BenSteffan.

We do not need higher homotopy groups. The fundamental group of a pointed space $(Y,y)$ will be understood as the set of pointed homotopy classes of maps $(S^1,s) \to (Y,y)$. Here $s$ is an arbitrary basepoint.
Let $f : X \to S^1$ and $g : S^1 \to X$ be homotopy equivalences which are inverse to each other, i.e. $g \circ f \simeq 1_X$ and $f \circ g \simeq 1_{S^1}$.
Let $i : A \to X$ denote inclusion. You have already shown that $f' = f\mid_A = f \circ i :A \to S^1$ and $g' = r \circ g : S^1 \to A$ have the property $g' \circ f' \simeq 1_A$.
Choose a basepoint $a \in A$ and let $s = f(a) \in S^1$. It is well-known  that $f_* : \pi_1(X,a) \to \pi_1(S^1,s)$ is an isomorphism. This is true for each homotopy equivalence, we do not need to assume that $f : (X,a) \to (S^1,s)$ is a pointed homotopy equivalence. See for example Hypothesis in homotopy equivalence inducing isomorphism in the fundamental groups.
We claim that $g$ is homotopic to a map $\bar g : S^1 \to X$ such that $\bar g(s) = a$. This can either be shown by using the fact that the pair $(S^1, \{s\})$ has the homotopy extension property or by the following argument:
Let $\bar g : (S^1,a) \to (X,a)$ be any representative of $f^{-1}_*([1_{S^1}])$, where $[-]$ denotes the pointed homotopy class in the fundamental group. Then $[f \circ \bar g] = f_*([\bar g]) = [1_{S^1}]$, in particular $f \circ \bar g \simeq 1_{S^1}$. We conclude $\bar g = 1_X \circ \bar g  \simeq g \circ f \circ \bar g \simeq g \circ 1_{S^1} = g$.
Thus we may w.l.o.g. assume that $g(s) = a$.
We claim that the homomorphism $g_* : \pi_1(S^1,s) \to \pi_1(X,a)$ is inverse to $f_* : \pi_1(X,a) \to \pi_1(S^1,s)$. In fact, we have $[g] = f^{-1}_*([1_{S^1}])$, thus $(f_* \circ g_*)([1_{S^1}]) = f_*(g_*([1_{S^1}]) = f_*([g]) = [1_{S^1}]$. Since $[1_{S^1}]$ is a generator of $\pi_1(S^1,s)$, we get $f_* \circ g_* = id$, i.e. $g_* = f^{-1}_*$.
Since $r$ is a retraction, the homomorphisms $i_* : \pi_1(A,a) \to \pi_1(X,a)$ and $r_* : \pi_1(X,a) \to \pi_1(A,a)$ satisfy $r_* \circ i_* = (1_A)_* = id$. Hence $r_*$ is surjective. By assumption it also injective, thus an isomorphism. We have $r^{-1}_* = r^{-1}_* \circ id = r^{-1}_* \circ r_*  \circ i_* = i_*$.
Therefore
$$f'_* \circ g'_* = f_* \circ i_* \circ r_* \circ g_* = id $$
which means
$$[f' \circ g'] = f'_*([g'])= f'_*(g'_*([1_{S^1}])) = (f'_* \circ g'_*)([1_{S^1}]) = [1_{S^1}] .$$
Hence
$$f' \circ g' \simeq 1_{S^1}.$$
